# Angular 4: Bind two HTML components with the same value

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am new to Angular.
I have a row in a table which is binded to the value item.md_id as shown below:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of driverData">
   <td class="align-right" id="md_id" [(ngModel)]="item.md_id" name="driverId" ngDefaultControl (click)="runPromo(item)">
        {{item.driver_name}}
   </td>
</tr>
```

I want to use that binded value in another HTML component of the same page:

```
<div>
  <button class="active"  id="md_id" [value]="item.md_id" (click)="runPromo(item.md_id)" >First</button>
</div>
```

I am able to retreive the value in the row of a table from the service.
But I am not able to use that particular value for my second HTML component
Could you please help.
Thanks

Comment: you are `binding` `ngModel` in `td`, I dont think you can do that.

Comment: if all you want it your `<tr>...</tr>` block again, you have to make it as a separate component

Comment: @manish No, I dont want my tr block again.I want to pass the retreived value from tr to the click button.

Comment: @Sravan Is there a solution for that

Comment: can you explain your question in little brief? I couldnt understand that

Comment: @Sravan Its pretty simple. There is a for loop defined in a table.Based on the value present in the row, the same value should be passed as an argument for my click event.

Comment: there is no need for `ngModel` it will pass by that `item` variable

Comment: its getting long here, have created a chat room, lets pitch in there
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169335/so-questions-discussion

Comment: where is that link?

Comment: @sravan But that way also it is not working

Comment: after you send that `item` what you need to do?

Comment: I want to send that item to my component service:   this.runPromo = (v) =>{ 
      this.calendarService.getPromoName(v.md_id).subscribe(data => this.promoName = data);
      this.calendarService.getData(v.md_id).subscribe(data => this.calendarTableSelected = data);
     }

Comment: are you getting data you needed? from `v.md_id` and `data`?

Comment: @Sravan: yes, I am able to get it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169337/discussion-between-sravan-and-neha-uniyal).

Comment: @sravan : But the same variable md_id I also want to pass through my second html component: <div>
  <button class="active"  id="md_id" [value]="item.md_id" (click)="runPromo(item.md_id)" >First</button>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

**Angular 2 or higher: *ngFor directive**

When you want to iterate an array and access to each element of it, you use *ngFor.
In this piece of your code:

```
   <tr *ngFor="let item of driverData">
      <td class="align-right" id="md_id" [(ngModel)]="item.md_id" name="driverId" ngDefaultControl (click)="runPromo(item)">
    {{item.driver_name}}
   </td>
   </tr>
```

**tr** tag iterate the list and in **td** tag you have access to list items and you can bind to input or any other html.

```
<div>
  <button class="active"  id="md_id" [value]="item.md_id" 
  (click)="runPromo(item.md_id)" >First</button>
</div>
```

You can’t access to the data of members outside of this loop unless you put your code inside the **td** tag.

**Notice:**
When you iterate a loop, members are only accessible inside the context of the loop.

Comment: Yeah that issue is resolved.But could you please help here in this quick question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49949020/angular-4-saving-variable-from-the-table-element-through-post-service