# Angular 4: Saving variable from the table element through POST service

Tags: javascript, python, html, angular, rest

I am new to Angular and I need help in saving the value from a table through a POST service. Below is my code.

```
saveCalendar(value: any) {
  console.log("Updated Value"+ value); // value from the table
  this.body = {
  "promotionname": this.promotionname,
  "period": this.period,
  "indicator": this.indicator,
  "value": this.value
};
this.services.saveCalendar(this.body)
.then(
 response => {
   if(response == "Success")
     {
       this.firstPage(this.clickedItem);
     }
 }
);

}
```

Service:

```
 saveCalendar(body: object): Promise<any> {

                return this.http.post(environment.serverUrl+'/api/update_promocal', body)
                  .toPromise()
                  .then(
                     response => {
                      if(response['_body'] == "Save Successful!")
                        {
                          return "Success";
                        }
                    } 

                  )
                  .catch(error => console.log('Error while getting response: '+error))
              }
```

Below is the service from the backend:

```
def update_promocal(request):

id1 = request.GET.get('id')
column = request.GET.get('column')
data = request.GET.get('data')

test = Promocal.objects.get(id = id1)

if column == 'promotionname':

    test.promotion_name = data

elif column == 'period':

    test.period = data

elif column == 'indicator':

    test.indicator = data

elif column == 'value':

    test.value = data

elif column == 'marketdriver':

    test.market_driver = data

else:

    test.save()




test.save()
```

I want to send this updated value back to the service via POST method so that it can be saved in the database.But I am missing out something.
Please help here.

Comment: are you getting any errors? You can try using subscribe, httpclient uses observables which you can subscribe to instead of toPromise() oncé the subscribe is called the other promise can be resolve. On the backend you can get the data by using var promotionname = req.body.get(‘promotionname’)

Comment: @oudekaas Ok. But before that I also wanted to ensure if my python service is able to implement the post method. In Postman, it is giving me 403 error. Could you please help me in checking this.

Comment: @oudekaas because apart from 403 there are no errors

Answer (score 0):

I found this bit, I have limited experiemce with python? Hopefully this works: 
def do_POST(self):
       # Doesn't do anything with posted data
       content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length']) # <--- Gets the size of data
       post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length) # <--- Gets the data itself
       self._set_headers()
       self.wfile.write("

## POST!

") Is the above everything you are using to catch the Post request?

403 is a forbidden error, indicating you either have no index.html or no permission to access the webserver.

Is your webserver local? In postman are you using the right address, ie could it be you use the wrong port? What port is you server listening to and are you using that port?